# Tagging questions involving NP-complete problems with [np]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Over the past few months I've found many questions where the OP asks for an algorithm that solves some particular problem, only to find in one of the answers that the problem is NP-complete or NP-hard.  For example, see [this problem about bitwise OR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11786856/501557), [this question about grouping related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11422149/501557), or [this problem about grouping people into houses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11172756/501557).

Would it be inappropriate for me to retag these questions by adding the [np](/questions/tagged/np) tag to them?  I feel that this would make it easier for people searching for information about NP-complete or NP-hard problems to find these questions, though that's more of a property of the *answer* than the *question*.

Comment: If that is not the topic of the question, I would not tag them as such.

Answer (score -1):

I personally don't have a problem with the retag, based on the examples you provided. I think you're right; having these tagged [np] will help others looking for NP-related information to find it.

I do think there is a danger of people using tags as their own personal categorization folders, and I don't endorse that.  The fact that the answers of the questions you link speak specifically to NP justify the practice in this case.